# Magento 2.2.8 exact search in backend

Tags: magento2, backend, search, order-grid, magento2.2.8

In the admin backend on the order grids we used to be able to do an exact search like, "Firstname" in Magento 2.2.5

Now i have upgraded Magento to 2.2.8 and the exact match doesn't work anymore. It seems like the fulltext search is broken. How can I fix that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the same question i have looked everywhere and still not answer

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/159399)